# How to get filtered result by using Hash Index in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, arangojs, arangodb-php

My data:

```
{
  "rootElement": {
    "names": {
      "name": [
        "Haseb",
        "Anil",
        "Ajinkya",
        {
          "city": "mumbai",
          "state": "maharashtra",
          "job": {
            "second": "bosch",
            "first": "infosys"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "places": {
      "place": {
        "origin": "INDIA",
        "current": "GERMANY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created a hash index on `job` field with the API:
http://localhost:8529/_db/_api/index?collection=Metadata

```
{
  "type": "hash",
  "fields": [
    "rootElement.names.name[*].jobs"
  ]
}
```

And I make the search query with the API:
http://localhost:8529/_db/_api/simple/by-example

```
{
  "collection": "Metadata",
  "example": {
    "rootElement.names.name[*].jobs ": "bosch"
  }
}
```

Ideally, only the document containing `job : bosch` should be returned as a result. But for me it gives all the documents in the array `name[*]`. Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: first hint: you should avoid simple queries if you can.

Comment: but it is the straight forward query for search

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Array asterisk operators are not supported by simple queries.

You need to use AQL for this:

```
FOR elem IN Metadata FILTER elem.rootElement.names.name[*].jobs = "bosch" RETURN elem
```

You can also execute [AQL via the REST interface](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpAqlQuery/index.html) - However you should rather try to let a driver do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: does in any way Arango handle nested array for fulltext indexing & searching ?

Comment: The ['translation' exampl](https://docs.arangodb.com/IndexHandling/Fulltext.html) demonstates the capabilities of the fulltext index. Deeper nesting is currently unsupported.